# Windows Forms app on shared location, save file locally

Tags: c#, winforms, export-to-excel

My problem is that I have a windows forms application which is located on a shared location, which is doing some logic and at the end i need to export the data into an excel file.

But the excel file should be exported to the machine that the users is logged in, not on the shared server where the application is hosted ...

Any Ideas?

Example of the situation:
The location of the application is at 192.168.1.150\AppName\App.exe

I have access to this shared location and I'm starting the exe file from there.
I need the application to export an excel file to my computer on my desktop .... how?

Comment: Pretty vague, if you're running the application locally then it would export locally, unless it connects to a server that does the work. You need to be more specific

Comment: I edited the question and added an example, to be more clear

Comment: I added code to my answer for getting the desktop folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think the folder "My Documents" is a good place to save the Excel file, then this code will help to get you the path:

`var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`

or if you want to put the file on the Desktop:

`var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)`

The code works regardless of where the folder "My Documents" (or "Desktop") is located for the user (C:, D:, Network share, etc), or which language version his windows installation is using.

To combine with a time based file name:

```
var fileName = $"your_file_{DateTime.Now:yyMMddHHmmss}.xlsx";
var fullPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);
```

I often use time based file names to not overwrite if there is a previous file. (It would of course overwrite if created the same second)

If you want a file name that is guaranteed to be unique you can use a `Guid` instead of `DateTime`:

```
var fileName = $"your_file_{Guid.NewGuid():N}.xlsx";
```

If the file is just used "within the program" you can also store it in the temporary files folder. To get the path to the temporary files folder you write `var folderPath = Path.GetTempPath()`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll try this solution later today and let you know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use Save File Dialog and save the excel file where you want? Something like this:

```
private void SaveFile_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   string name = SaveFile.FileName;
   string[] savearray = new string[] { "some test:" }
   File.WriteAllLines(name, savearray);
   //this is just an example, your excel file goes here.
}
```

And on your button to save:

```
SaveFile.ShowDialog();
```

You can choose the path for where you want to save...

Comment: Yea, this would be the alternative if I don't find a solution

Comment: For me this is the easiest and fastest way to do what you want. I'm going to search a little bit and try to find another way.
Don't forget to accept the best answer.